Design a controller using root locus technique
Given the system described by the transfer function
$$P(s)=10/(s^2 +1)$$
Design a controller using root locus technique so that:

The closed loop system is of first type and $$|e_1|<=0.01$$
The closed loop system has all the poles p_i with $$Re[p_i]<=-1$$

Solution of point 1:
The system has to be type 1 so I have to put:
$$ G(s)=(k_g)/s $$ so I have: $$ |e_1|<=0.01<=>|(k_d)/((k_g)∗(k_p))|<=0.01 $$
where: $$ k_d=1 $$
and
$$(k_p)=P(0)=10 $$
so i have :
$$ 1/(10∗(k_g))<=0.01<=>(k_g)>=10 $$
I can solve this type of exercise when the poles of the transfer function are real, but how can I solve it when they're imaginary?
Thank you for reading
EDIT
Here is the solution of a similar exercise I solved where the transfer function has only real poles:
$$ P(s) = 1/(s^2 -1) $$
My question regards a different function, which has complex poles, I hope you can help.
This is the solution of the similar exercise:
https://www.dropbox.com/t/seKMvXmeeaFZPXEE
(it's a OneNote page because the exported PDF cut some parts I don't know why)

Please describe what you've already done to solve it and where you're stuck. This makes it easier to answer your Question without repeating Parts you already know.

@kruemi i will add the resolution of a similar exercise as a OneNote Page in the question, the exercise i solved refers to a DIFFERENT transfer function with REAL pole, i'll leave to you guys the question with the complex poles one

@RussellH as i already told kruemi yes i will add more context
